# On PopupWindowClose, mainpage redirect

Tags: asp.net

I'm working on the following scenario:

- A button got clicked in main page.
- popupWindow show up.
- A button got clicked in popupwindow.
- The popupwindow would be closed and the mainpage redirect.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

use javascript for this.
use this code in popup window button click .

```
window.close();
window.opener.location.reload();
```